# HTML text columns with different responsive padding in each column

Tags: html, css, text, responsive, padding

I am helping out with some coding - which is not my fortay - and as part of a page, we are wanting to include and embed video and in a column to the right is a title for the video.
I am using HTML columns to allow them to show underneath each other on mobile. But because I want the title to show vertically aligned in the centre of the video, the responsive version has a big gap due to the 
 I have had to use for the desktop version to look ok. I know this isn't the best way but I have tried using different padding in the .column styles, but because it appears to both, it's not giving me the look I need.

Is there any way of fixing this so there is a large padding on desktop but small-to-none on mobile?

```html
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <iframe src="VIDEO URL" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <center>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><p class="rtecenter"><p style="font-size:24pt; color:#0060a9;"><strong>VIDEO TITLE </strong></p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Tried using the responsive style to add padding or trying to create a second column style but then the columns don't show floating next to each other.

Comment: @Paulie_D there is in the .column style - I have removed the rest because I couldn't get it to work. I had added it to the second column within the p style tag.

I ideally need each column to have different top padding for both desktop and mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly do something like this?

What I did was got rid of all the `<br>` you used to manually "center" the title and simply added some CSS to style the `row` in order to align the items in the center, then kind of "undid" it in the media query by setting the row to `inline-block`

```html
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}



/* Clear floats after the columns */


/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .row {
    display:inline-block;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
<iframe src="VIDEO URL" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <center>
    <p class="rtecenter"><p style="font-size:24pt; color:#0060a9;"><strong>VIDEO TITLE </strong></p>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks - that has helped loads. Still a big gap in mobile few but I know think that is an issue with the site settings.